# How to fix my cross-origin request blocked for spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

I am running my angular app through nginx against several spring boot services in the back. I am using nginx proxy_pass to strip the encryption and redirect the port to the one used by the service. This is my test server, so all of these are calling each other through localhost.

When I attempt to login, I'm getting the following error in my firefox console.

```
OPTIONShttp://localhost/location-api/location/login?payload={%22username%22:%22toddhehl%22,%22password%22:%22nunyons%22}
[HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway 1ms]

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/location-api/location/login?payload={%22username%22:%22toddhehl%22,%22password%22:%22nunyons%22}. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Here is the section of my nginx configuration that is relevant.

```
    location /location-api/ {
        access_log /dev/stdout upstream_logging;
        set $upstream http://localhost:8093/;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
```

And 8093 is where my spring boot application is running. At the top of my controller, I have:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true")
@RestController(value = "/location")
public class LocationController {
```

I don't really understand what allowCredentials does, but I tried it to see if it would fix my problem.

Here's the entire transaction.

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "82.0.3"
    },
    "browser": {
      "name": "Firefox",
      "version": "82.0.3"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2020-11-16T16:37:36.363-05:00",
        "id": "page_1",
        "title": "PizzaCloudAdmin",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": -5572,
          "onLoad": -5301
        }
      }
    ],
    "entries": [
      {
        "pageref": "page_1",
        "startedDateTime": "2020-11-16T16:37:36.363-05:00",
        "request": {
          "bodySize": 0,
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "url": "http://localhost/location-api/location/login?payload={%22username%22:%22toddhehl%22,%22password%22:%22nunyons%22}",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "localhost"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Request-Method",
              "value": "POST"
            },
            {
              "name": "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
              "value": "access-control-allow-origin"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "https://essos"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "payload",
              "value": "{\"username\":\"toddhehl\",\"password\":\"nunyons\"}"
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 451
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 502,
          "statusText": "Bad Gateway",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Server",
              "value": "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Mon, 16 Nov 2020 21:37:36 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/html"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "166"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "size": 0,
            "text": ""
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 166,
          "bodySize": 166
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 0,
          "dns": 0,
          "connect": 0,
          "ssl": 0,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 0,
          "receive": 0
        },
        "time": 0,
        "_securityState": "insecure",
        "serverIPAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "connection": "80"
      },
      {
        "pageref": "page_1",
        "startedDateTime": "2020-11-16T16:37:36.369-05:00",
        "request": {
          "bodySize": 0,
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "http://localhost/location-api/location/login?payload={%22username%22:%22toddhehl%22,%22password%22:%22nunyons%22}",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "localhost"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-allow-origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/plain"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "https://essos"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "queryString": [
            {
              "name": "payload",
              "value": "{\"username\":\"toddhehl\",\"password\":\"nunyons\"}"
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 0,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {},
          "redirectURL": "",
          "bodySize": -1
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {},
        "time": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've done bunches of searches and have tried everything I've found and now I'm simply good and stuck and am looking for counsel. The thing I want the most, the URL that comes out of nginx, doesn't seem to be accessible.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: The error message cited in the question shows that the root problem is a 502 Bad Gateway error. The CORS message is just a side effect of that 502 error — because it’s normal and expected that any 502 error won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. As far as troubleshooting the cause of the 502 error, you need to check the server logs and see what messages the server is logging there before it sends the 502 response.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following nginx configuration change?

```
    location /location-api/ {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET';
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }
        set $upstream http://localhost:8093;
        rewrite ^/location-api(.*) $1 break;
        access_log /dev/stdout upstream_logging;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET';
    }
```

If you also need to support the `POST` method, add it to the allowed methods list.

Comment: Tried it. No change. Thanks!

Comment: What URI path is expected by your backend? Is it `/location-api/location/login` or `/location/login`? (As of your current config you are passing the request URI as `/location/login`)

Comment: /location/login

Comment: @Thom Can you try the updated one? Note the `rewrite` directive and `set $upstream http://localhost:8093;` without the trailing slash.

Comment: One more update - `set` directive should be **before** the `rewrite ... break;` one in order to be executed.

Comment: No change on the error, but I'm no longer getting the error on the OPTIONS command. May have been the last change too.

Comment: @Thom Can you show all the HTTP response headers from the rejected request?

Comment: Added headers. Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. See [this](https://pastebin.com/XLZQAQ7T) example what I'm looking for (this is from Chrome, but Firefox has the same abilities in DevTools). Do you add `POST` as the supported method? `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST';`

Comment: Yes, added POST as supported method.

Comment: How about now? Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Comment: That's much better. I'm curious how such kind of JSON can be achieved. Is it Firefox DevTools feature? Now back to your question. As I can see there is still a 502 Bad Gateway error on the OPTIONS request. That does not make any sense to me, configurations like that (`if ($request_method = OPTIONS) { ... return 204; }`) has been used many times without any problems. You should have some nginx error log entry for this error (as for any 50x errors), can you find that line and add it to your question?

Comment: OK. Let me try a few things. I'm finding it impossible to get logs out of my docker container.

Comment: Also, I just created a HAR file and copied that in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224667/discussion-between-thom-and-ivan-shatsky).